# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: tes.sales.bean.DocumentosBean@1821df11.onTestEvent(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)

Tags: jsf, checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I have problems with the selection checkbox in datatable, I add a ajax with "rowSelectCheckbox" event and to select a checkbox suge the following error:

> WARNING: Method not found:
>   tes.sales.bean.DocumentosBean@1821df11.onTestEvent(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)
>   javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found:
>   tes.sales.bean.DocumentosBean@1821df11.onTestEvent(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)
>     at
>   org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:245)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)  at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processCustomListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:72)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent.processListener(SelectEvent.java:40)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> jul 06, 2015 5:05:21 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl
>   handlePartialResponseError SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:
>   Method not found:
>   tes.sales.bean.DocumentosBean@1821df11.onTestEvent(org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent)
>     at
>   org.apache.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:245)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:271)  at
>   org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processCustomListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:72)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent.processListener(SelectEvent.java:40)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:804)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1086)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="myTable" var="mydoc" value="#{DocumentosBean.documentos}" rows="20" paginator="true" sortOrder="descending"
                        selection="#{DocumentosBean.selectedDocs}" filteredValue="#{DocumentosBean.myFilter}"
                        sortBy="#{mydoc.id}" rowKey="#{mydoc.id}" rowIndexVar="indexRow">

<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"  listener="#{DocumentosBean.onTestEvent}" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" process="@this"/>
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="@this"/>      


<p:column selectionMode="multiple"  style="min-width:20px;text-align:center;"></p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mydoc.id}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Vendedor">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mydoc.vendedor}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Moneda">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mydoc.moneda}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Operación">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mydoc.operacion}" />
                </p:column>

                 <p:column headerText="Fecha Creación">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mydoc.fechaCreacion}" />
                </p:column>


                 <p:column headerText="Estado">
                    <h:outputText value="#{mydoc.estado}" />
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>


            </h:form>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="DocumentosBean")
@SessionScoped
public class DocumentosBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private List<ListaDocumentos> documentos; 
        private ListaDocumentos selectedDoc;
        private ListaDocumentos[] selectedDocs;     
        private List<ListaDocumentos> myFilter; 

        public DocumentosBean() {
            System.out.println("SelectEvent");
            documentos = new ArrayList<ListaDocumentos>();

            fillData(documentos);
            /*myFilter = new ArrayList<ListaDocumentos>();
            fillData(myFilter);*/
        }
        public void onTestEvent(SelectEvent e){
        System.out.println(".......");
        System.out.println(e.getObject().toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid the obvious, did you properly clean, rebuild, redeploy and restart after editing the code? You may just not be running the code you think you're running.

Comment: Also make sure you have right import i.e. *import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;*

Comment: BalusC, you're right, besides that add lib jsf 2 myFaces apache api 2.0.2